# Automatic result from array via data from any input types

Tags: php, arrays

I have a trouble regarding to my project it's about Order System just a simple one.. My concern is how am i going to compare the value of my input from my form to the array I created,  then it will automatically declare the price of the item i pick with just only the name of the item. Here is my code.. PLs help.

WELCOME TO SIMPLE CARENDERYA!!!
    Simple Order Sytem

```
<div class="container">
 <!-- Menu -->
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <thead>
                <th>Menu</th>
                <th>Price:</th>
                <th>Drinks</th>
                <th>Price:</th>
            </thead>
        </tr>   
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:red;">Fried Chicken</td>
                <td>P 300.00</td>
                <td style="color:red;">Coke</td>
                <td>P 25.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:red;">Adobong Baboy</td>
                <td>P 400.00</td>
                <td style="color:red;">Sprite</td>
                <td>P 25.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:red;">Spaghetti</td>
                <td>P 500.00</td>
                <td style="color:red;">Iced Tea</td>
                <td>P 30.00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="color:red;">Barbeque</td>
                <td>P 600.00</td>
                <td style="color:red;">Pineapple Juice</td>
                <td>P 25.00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    


    <!-- end menu -->



    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <form class="form" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pick">Select your order (select one):</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="pick" id="pick">
                        <option value="None">None</option>
                        <option value="Sample1">Fried Chicken</option>
                        <option value="Sample2">Abobong Baboy</option>
                        <option value="Sample3">Spaghetti</option>
                        <option value="Sample4">Barbeque</option>   
                    </select>   
            </div>  

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="amount">Select your amount:</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="amount" name="amount">
                        <option value="None">None</option>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        <option value="5">5</option>    
                    </select>   
            </div>  


    </div>  

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="drinks">Select Drinks:</label>
                <select id="drinks" name="drinks" class="form-control">
                    <option>None</option>
                    <option value="Coke">Coke</option>
                    <option>Sprite</option>
                    <option>Iced Tea</option>
                    <option>Pineapple Juice</option>
                </select>   
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="drinks-amount">Select Drinks:</label>
                <select id="drinks-amount" name="drinks-amount" class="form-control">
                    <option>None</option>
                    <option>1</option>
                    <option>2</option>
                    <option>3</option>
                    <option>4</option>
                </select>   
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-danger"  name="submit" type="submit">PAY</button>


        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <h3 class="white">Total:</h3>

        <?php

         if (isset($_POST['submit']))
         {
            $pick = $_POST['pick'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            $drinks = $_POST['drinks'];
            $drinks_amount = $_POST['drinks-amount'];

            $menu = array( 'Sample1' => '300.00', 'Sample2' => '400.00', 'Sample3' => '500.00', 'Sample4' => '600.00' );
            $beverage = array( 'Coke' => '25.00', 'Sprite' => '25.00' );

            $order1 = '';
            $order2 = '';

            //Condition 1
            if( $pick == 'Sample1' || $drinks == 'Coke' )
            {
                $order1 = $menu['Sample1'] * $amount;
                $order2 = $beverage['Coke'] * $drinks_amount;


                $total = $order1 + $order2;

                echo '<h2 class="white">','P '.$total.' . 00','</h2>';
                echo '<button class="btn btn-warning"  name="view" type="reset">Show Order</button>';
                return $total;

            }


            //Condition 2
            elseif( $pick == 'Sample2' || $drinks == 'Coke' )
            {
                $order1 = $menu['Sample2'] * $amount;
                $order2 = $beverage['Coke'] * $drinks_amount;


                $total = $order1 + $order2;

                echo '<h2 class="white">','P '.$total.' . 00','</h2>';
                echo '<button class="btn btn-warning"  name="view" type="reset">Show Order</button>';
                return $total;
            }

            //Condition 3
            elseif( $pick == 'Sample3' || $drinks == 'Coke' )
            {
                $order1 = $menu['Sample3'] * $amount;
                $order2 = $beverage['Coke'] * $drinks_amount;


                $total = $order1 + $order2;

                echo '<h2 class="white">','P '.$total.' . 00','</h2>';
                echo '<button class="btn btn-warning"  name="view" type="reset">Show Order</button>';
                return $total;
            }

            //Condition 4
            elseif( $pick == 'Sample4' || $drinks == 'Coke' )
            {
                $order1 = $menu['Sample4'] * $amount;
                $order2 = $beverage['Coke'] * $drinks_amount;


                $total = $order1 + $order2;

                echo '<h2 class="white">','P '.$total.' . 00','</h2>';
                echo '<button class="btn btn-warning"  name="view" type="reset">Show Order</button>';
                return $total;
            }




            else
            {
                echo '<h2 class="white">P 0.00</h2>';
                echo '<h3 style="color:red;">Sorry You Dont have an Order..</h3>';
            }




        }

        ?>
    </div>
```

Well, it is working guys but i really want to shorten my codes with the same Output.So guys pls help me out.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear to me but you can use `array_key_exists`. Basically, instead of having all of those conditions you can have the following single condition: `$order1 = 0; $order2 = 0; if(array_key_exists($pick, $menu) && array_key_exists($drinks, $beverage)) { $order1 = $menu[$pick] * $amount; $order2 = $beverage[$drinks] * $drinks_amount;} $total = $order1 + $order2;`

Answer (score 0):

i tried to fix your code. I'll hope that it is exactly what you need.

```
<?php

         if (isset($_POST['submit']))
         {
            $pick = $_POST['pick'];
            $amount = $_POST['amount'];
            $drinks = $_POST['drinks'];
            $drinks_amount = $_POST['drinks-amount'];

            $menu = array( 'Sample1' => '300.00', 'Sample2' => '400.00', 'Sample3' => '500.00', 'Sample4' => '600.00' );
            $beverage = array( 'Coke' => '25.00', 'Sprite' => '25.00' );

            //Try to do not mix Strings with numbers.
            $order1 = 0;
            $order2 = 0;

            //First check if your variables are empty or not.
            if(isset($pick) && trim($pick) != null){
                //if the variable pick has a value check if the key is a key of the array
                if(array_key_exists($pick,$menu)){
                    $order1 = $menu[pick] * $amount;
                }else{
                    echo "Select a correct menu";
                }
            }

            if(isset($drinks) && trim($drinks) != null){
                //if the variable $drinks has a value
                if(array_key_exists($drinks,$beverage)){
                    $order2 = $beverage[$drinks] * $drinks_amount;
                }else{
                    echo "Select a correct drink";
                }
            }


            $total = $order1 + $order2;

            echo '<h2 class="white">','P '.$total.' . 00','</h2>';
            echo '<button class="btn btn-warning"  name="view" type="reset">Show Order</button>';
            //if your code is in a function use return. If not you don't need it
            return $total;
     }

?>
```

You can obviously make it using one single if statement. I have divided the two in order to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. but when i run the codes you gave me... my server detect an error like this.

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in C:\xampp\htdocs\website\includes\header.php on line 126


how can i fix this?

Comment: Ok so try to separate the two conditions in that way :    if(isset($pick) && trim($pick) != null){}

Answer (score 0):

There is a much simpler way to do this:

```
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $pick = $_POST['pick'];
        $amount = $_POST['amount'];
        $drinks = $_POST['drinks'];
        $drinks_amount = $_POST['drinks-amount'];

        $menu = array( 'Fried Chicken' => '300.00',
               'Abobong Baboy' => '400.00', 
               'Spaghetti' => '500.0', 
               'Coke' => '25.00', 
               'Sprite' => '25.00');

        if( array_key_exists($pick,$menu) {
            $total = $menu[$pick] * $amount + (($drinks == 'Coke')? $menu[$drinks] * $drinks_amount : 0 );

            echo '<h2 class="white">','P '.$total.' . 00','</h2>';
            echo '<button class="btn btn-warning"  name="view" type="reset">Show Order</button>';
            return $total;

        } else {
            echo '<h2 class="white">P 0.00</h2>';
            echo '<h3 style="color:red;">Sorry You Dont have an Order..</h3>';
        }
```